# Why my Shell code always return Even, even if number is odd

Tags: shell

I am using this code to check if user's input (which is always number) is even or odd, but the script always return "Even"

```bash
read -p "Enter a number: " x
if ((x % 2 == 0));
   then echo "Even"; 
   else echo "Odd"; 
fi
```

I am using this test:

```rb
def solution(x)
  puts("Number: #{x}")
  run_shell(args: [x]).strip
end

describe "Solution" do
  it "should print 'Even' for even numbers" do
    [0, 2, 4, 78, 100000, 1545452, -2, -10, -123456]
      .each { |x| expect(solution(x)).to eq('Even') }
  end
  
  it "should print 'Odd' for odd numbers" do
    [1, 3, 5, 77, 100001, 1545455, -1, -3, -9, -12345]
      .each { |x| expect(solution(x)).to eq('Odd') }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ruby code passes arguments *on the shell script's command line*, but the shell script is looking for arguments *on its standard input stream*.

Because in an arithmetic context the shell treats an empty string like a 0, you get a result of always-even.

Consider reading from stdin only when you haven't been provided input on the command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $1 ]]; then
  x=$1
else
  read -p 'Enter a number: ' x
fi

if ((x % 2 == 0)); then
  echo "Even"
else
  echo "Odd"
fi
```